# Girl cutting hair to short length and roughly when broke

Tags: analysis

Why is it shown in many movies and drama that when a girl is broke, she cut her long beautiful hair to short length.
What is emotional or psychological effect of cutting hair?

Comment: Maybe to sell her long hair.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Britney Spears ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "broke". Do you mean "out of money" or "broken"? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Do you really mean "broke" as "Has no money/bankrupt" or did you wanted to say something else? because i never saw it in a movie that a girl did this because she lost all her money...

Comment: I am sure broke means emotional drama here not financial

Comment: See also Ritchie Tennenbaum shaving his beard and cutting his hair short before attempting suicide in *The Royal Tennenbaums*, and Ron Swanson's mustache in its various states of growth and shaving in *Parks and Recreation*. Also Samson's hair holding his power in The Bible.

Answer (score 7):

A haircut, especially for someone with long hair, is often a difficult and emotional step, since growing hair out takes years. Thus, it's often used to signify a dramatic change for the character, either leaving the old life or old trauma behind to start anew.

TVTropes is a good source for many such uses in film and TV which can be a great resource to see the uses that haircuts are put to - once you've managed to extricate yourself from the site, of course.

The primary trope relevant here is, I think, [Important Haircut](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ImportantHaircut):

> When a character cuts off their hair, it often symbolizes a rite of passage or bout of character growth. A princess striking out on an adventure, or a new recruit at boot camp, for instance. Hair is something that takes time and effort to grow, so parting with it voluntarily can be a powerful act.